# Id.exe cannot find -llapack -lblas

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda to work with python. For my problem I need to use an external package which does not come with Anaconda namely CVXOPT (for convex optimisation problems).
And I do the following:

[image]

However, I am running into the following problem:

[image]

How can I overcome this? Apparently mingw32/bin/Id.exe needs LAPACK, BLAS

Please note that I am running Windows 7 (x64 bit), but I kept all my coding libraries/packages as x32